# How to programmatically generate custom text in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, chunks

I'm trying to get this markdown chunk into R code, so I can use it programmatically. The output is a word document and it works perfectly. I just to get that chunk into a variable, so I can copy, paste and modify it whenever I need it.

These are two examples of markdown chunks that I need to get into a variable.

1:

```
::: {custom-style="heading 3"}
Caudal
:::
```

2:

```
::: {custom-style="Cuadro (texto al pie)"}
Fuente: `r fuente`\
Elaborado por: `r elaborado_por`
:::
```

I need to generate something like this:

````
pie_chart <- 
'``` {custom-style="Cuadro (texto al pie)"}
Fuente: `r fuente`\
Elaborado por: `r elaborado_por`
```'
````

```
text text
pie_chart
```

Result:

```
text text
Fuente: aaa
Elaborado por: aaa
```

I looked for a solution in https://github.com/Rapporter/pander but I didn't find any.

Comment: The `knit_expand` function might do what you need. See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitr/vignettes/knit_expand.html), [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/knit-expand.html), and [here](https://jdblischak.github.io/workflowr/articles/wflow-07-common-code.html).

Comment: Please consider [parameterized reports in Rmarkdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/parameterized-reports.html) This is exactly how you programmatically input text for reporting in Rmarkdown. I understand this is not a Word .doc output, just look at how this would help you get what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `result='asis'` chunck option and output custom text with `cat`:

````
```{r, results = 'asis', echo = FALSE}

cat('
```{custom-style="heading 3"}
Caudal
```')

```
````